# need help on css class to override font size in modern communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, communication-site

I am using an SPFX extension listed here: https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss to inject css in modern communication site.

I just need to know which css class should I use to override current font size for the global navigation. Can someone please help, thanks.
[image]

Comment: can you share screenshot of global navigation?

Comment: Just added, I am not sure from top level, what class to use to make sure the navigation font size can be increased, Home is a hub site and operations is a team site, I will have more team site links over the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following CSS style for your reference.

```
<style>
.ms-HubNav-nameLink{
    font-size:18px !important;
}
.ms-HorizontalNavItem-link{
    font-size:18px !important;
    padding:0 !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks LZ_MSFT always for helping.This works and increases font size for all the links including hub site link. One issue, I am seeing is by default (before adding CSS), the hub site link is not aligning with the team site links, please see screenshot added in the question description, is this by design?

Comment: Add padding:0; in ms-HorizontalNavItem-link class, I modify the code, you can check if.

Comment: Excellent thank you, that works.

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is to fire up the console inspector and point to the items you are looking to customize

not sure if we're using the same site/nav, but this might be the one you are looking for:

```
/*modern*/
.ms-HorizontalNavItem-link {
    font-size: 16px;
}

/*classic*/
.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.static > .ms-core-listMenu-item {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: thanks Tiago, this works for the team site links and does a great job. However the hub site link does not get affected by the css, is there a different css class needs to be used for hub site link called Home?

Comment: you should check if your style is getting injected. either that or it might be using the classic mode. give it a try. answer updated

Comment: classic site uses master page concept...to add css on classic site you have to add it in master page